# validate that its the correct file path and delimeter

Tags: xml, vb.net

I want to validate that my delimiter exists. I am using vb.net with xml files

I have the validation for the fil working however I want the code to validtae the delimiter first and then if there are NO ERRORS for the validation to continue on to the file. My errors go to a messgae box. The delimiter is used to tell if the content is seperated by tabs(T), comma(C) etc. Any code samples would be very helpful.

```
 '-- Validate the delimiter exists
        Dim lstMsgs As New List(Of String)
        Dim strdelimiter As String = Me.TextBox1.Text

        '--Validate the file exists
        Dim strFilNme As String = Me.txtFilNme.Text

        '-- delimiter
        If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox1) = True Then 'OrElse IO. (TextBox1) = False Then
            lstMsgs.Add("No delimiter chosen, please choose one of the following: T, S, C, SC ")
        End If

        '--file
        If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox2) OrElse IO.File.Exists(TextBox2) = False Then
            lstMsgs.Add("This filename invalid.")
        End If

        If lstMsgs.Count > 0 Then
            MsgBox(Strings.Join(lstMsgs.ToArray, vbCrLf))
            Exit Sub

        End If
```

I want the code to validtae the delimiter first and then if there are NO ERRORS for the validation to continue on to the file.

Comment: Have you thought about putting a list of valid delimiters in a combobox or listbox and then just check to ensure that something is selected (not listindex of -1). This would alleviate anyone typing an invalid delimiter because your check is only looking for an empty textbox.

Comment: Do you have Option Strict On ? Some of these should not work, for example, String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox1), should not work since TextBox1 isn't a string but a textbox.

Comment: Hi charles, I have just put a combobox in there great idea thanks. so now with my code I need to still produce an error If user not select an option in my combo box? and end the validation there with an error message so as it doesnt continue on to validate the file exists. could you help with this please.

Comment: If the SelectedIndex has a value of -1 then nothing is selected. So a simple If statement against it should suffice. Just remember to exit sub to stop further execution of the code block.

Comment: Dim lstMsgs As New List(Of String)
        'Dim strdelimiter As String = Me.TextBox1.Text

        '--Validate the file exists
        Dim strFilNme As String = Me.txtFilNme.Text                                                                                                             
        If combobox1.SelectedIndex = False Then
            lstMsgs.Add("No delimiter chosen, please choose one of the following: T, S, C, SC ")
        End If
        Exit Sub

Comment: this is what I have and it doesnt seem to be producing the error

Comment: I have also tried combobox1.SelectedIndex < 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close but here's your code, adjusted. Keep in mind, lstMsgs will not display anything as it is a list(of String). If you want to prompt a message to the user use MessageBox instead.

```
   Dim lstMsgs As New List(Of String)
    'Dim strdelimiter As String = Me.TextBox1.Text '--Validate the file exists
    Dim strFilNme As String = Me.txtFilNme.Text
    If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
        lstMsgs.Add("No delimiter chosen, please choose one of the following: T, S, C, SC ")
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

again, if you want a prompt to display change the lstMsgs.Add line to:

```
MessageBox.Show("No delimiter chosen, please choose one of the following: T, S, C, SC ")
```

You also want the exit sub inside the if block because you only want to exit the routine if this error occurs. Your attempt would have always stopped execution regardless of the outcome of the if statement.